# Can't upgrade linux-firmware package due to conflicting AthrBT firmware

Tags: package-management, updates

I have been using Ubuntu for the past one month or so. I get this message whenever I tried to download updates. What do I do? Please help to resolve.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which came with the Dell desktop I purchased.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 238206 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu', which is also in package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb
```

Comment: No response till now...? Does anybody have any idea how I fix this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/555961/374029 ..worked for me. remove the atheros bluetooth firmware.